# How to avoid typing the same path on the terminal?

Tags: bash

There is a **relative** path that I keep on typing, let's say `d1/d2/d3`. My sessions look like this:

```
annoying_path=d1/d2/d3
$ cd /k1
$ vim $annoying_path/subdir1/file.txt
$ vim $annoying_path/subdir2/file.txt
$ cd /k2
$ cat $annoying_path/subdir3/a.tar.gz > /dev/null
$ mv $annoying_path/subdir4/file.txt $annoying_path/subdir4/file2.txt
```

- I'm not really using `$annoying_path` because my system does not autocomplete paths that way. I have to copy/paste frequently.
- I still want to have my home directory.

Having a key combo to paste the path would probably work fine.

I'm using mac, iterm2, bash, ssh, tmux.

Thanks!

Comment: might not what you want: check [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), after configuration, you can do `vim $FZF_PERFIX_ON_YOUR_CONFIG`, and press `tab`, will show up search pane, you can type in like `subdir3/a.tar.gz` or `a.tar.gz`, it will show full path, press Enter to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possibilities:

1. In Bash, after typing `$annoying_path` hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to expand `$annoying_path` inline, so <kbd>Tab</kbd> will work to autocomplete further components. But this may misbehave if `$annoying_path` needs to be double-quoted (in general [it does need to be double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)). If you want to use this method then consider a shorter name for the variable. Note <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> can expand more (e.g. aliases).
2. `bind '"\C-x\C-a":"d1/d2/d3"'` in Bash will allow you to "paste" `d1/d2/d3` in the command line upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. Add the command to your `~/.bashrc` to make the binding permanent for interactive Bash. Add `"\C-x\C-a":"d1/d2/d3"` to your `~/.inputrc` to make the binding permanent for any program that uses readline  (including Bash).
3. The following snippet will also work in Bash:

   ```
   annoying_path=d1/d2/d3
   _insert_annoying_path() {
   READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$annoying_path${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
   READLINE_POINT="$(($READLINE_POINT+${#annoying_path}))"
   }
   bind -x '"\C-x\C-a":_insert_annoying_path'
   ```

   This is a quick and dirty solution that (upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) pastes the content of `$annoying_path` into the command line. Tested in Bash 5.0.3 (I'm not sure the solution will work well in Bash 4 with multi-byte characters in the command line). The advantage over the previous solution is the value of `$annoying_path` is not hardcoded, you can change it and the keystroke will start using the new value.
4. In a shell inside tmux run `tmux bind-key -T prefix a send-keys -l 'd1/d2/d3'`. This will allow you to "paste" `d1/d2/d3` upon <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> (the default <kbd>prefix</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>). The solution will work for any program inside tmux: you hit the keystroke and tmux types the string for you, regardless of the running program. To make the binding permanent add `bind-key -T prefix a send-keys -l 'd1/d2/d3'` to your `~/.tmux.conf` (keep in mind the file is read when the tmux server starts, or on demand (`tmux source ~/.tmux.conf`)).

Comment: Thanks, #4 is my favorite and it works perfectly. This ends years of suffering :)